# Why are the coordinates at the grid not correct in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, mapping, utm

**UPDATE:** The answer with the Decimal values for the grid, that has already helped.
But It still seems to be incorrect. Y=0 Is not aligned to Greenwich.
See Image 3 at the bottom of the page....

I wanted to create a map with coordinates in QGIS. But the coordinates are shown incorrectly. See image 1.
My Projection system is UTM 33N WGS84 (EPSG 32633). What am I doing wrong? For reference, Image 2 below of the

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show a grid in WGS84 (degrees) where the 0 Meridian goes through Greenwich, you should select the correct EPSG Code for your grid (EPSG 4326), see picture below.
In the map there are two grids plotted, the red one is the 32633 Grid like you did. The central meridian from a UTM grid is per definition at 500000 meters, so the zero meridian goes 500000 meters west of the central meridian for that UTM zone. As you see, the black grid is defined as 4326 and shows the lat lon values with the central meridian going through Greenwich...
[image]

[image]